# Open PDF on the last page using PdfViewr

Tags: android, pdf

I use [PdfViewr](https://github.com/barteksc/AndroidPdfViewer)

i want to open pdf on last page which i stopped in it

i used this code

```
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/Rewayat/"+name+".pdf");
    pdfView = (PDFView) findViewById(R.id.pdfView);

        pdfView.fromFile(file)
                .enableSwipe(true)
                .swipeHorizontal(false)
                .enableDoubletap(true)
                .defaultPage(pageNumber)
                .enableAnnotationRendering(false)
                .password(null)
                .scrollHandle(new DefaultScrollHandle(this))
                .onPageChange(this)
                .load();
```

and use this code to know page when change

```
@Override
public void onPageChanged(int page, int pageCount) {
    pageNumber = page;
}
```

please tell me how i can save last page for pdf using this codes

sorry for my bad English

Comment: Store `pageNumber` in `SharedPreferences`.

Comment: thanks bro sorry i'm new in android i will search about it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i used this code

```
@Override
public void onPageChanged(int page, int pageCount) {
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putInt(name,page);
    editor.commit();
}
```

thanks to CommonsWare